# Confusing answers - Azure Openai integration with Servicenow

Tags: openai-api, servicenow, chatgpt-api, gpt-3, servicenow-rest-api

I'm facing a curious problem. I created a gpt-35-turbo deployment within Azure Openai Studio, defined a persona and am consuming this deployment via API in Servicenow. However, the responses coming from Azure are completely random and do not match the persona chosen within Azure. Can anyone give me a tip on where I can adjust it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBRV5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Java.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkYQk.png)

I tried to change the parameters in the JSON, such as temperature and model used, but without success.